# The error message says browserRouter is not defined when using cdn in a html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to do this in a single html page. I first use unpkg.com to import the required things such as React and React-router-dom. If I use simple React staff, the page can load. Then I am trying to use React-router-dom, I add the script in the head tag and create a simple mydiv7. It shows an error message. Please help me see what is wrong with this code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        
      </head>
      <body>
  
 
    
    <div id="mydiv7"></div>
        
    <script type="text/babel">
    
    const Layout = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    
          <Outlet />
        </>
      )
    };
    
    const Home = () => {
      return <h1>Home</h1>;
    };
    
    
    const Blogs = () => {
      return <h1>Blog Articles</h1>;
    };
    
    
    const Contact = () => {
      return <h1>Contact Me</h1>;
    };
    
    
    const NoPage = () => {
      return <h1>404</h1>;
    };
    
        
    function App() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
              <Route index element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
              
              <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mydiv7'));
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import BrowserRouter according with [documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).
You can import with cdn using referenfes to window, like this.

```
const BrowserRouter = window.ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
```

Comment: Why don't I need "import React from "react";"?    I see some script need this, but I can go without it.    For example, function Hello() {
        return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
      }.  ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('mydiv'));

Comment: Now the error becomes "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Routes')" Is there anything wrong with other parts of the code?

Comment: You need to import all part of library you want. Link, Route ecc... In the same way.

Comment: I already did that as the other answer suggests, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe somewhere in your script you need to reference the react router package like you do with `React` for `react` and `ReactDOM` for `react-dom`.

From what I can tell `react-router-dom` is exported as `ReactRouterDOM`.

[HTML Script Tags](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/installation.md#html-script-tags)

Load the CDN links for the specific version of `react-router-dom` being used. Current is v6.1.1.

> ```
> <!-- Load React Router and React Router DOM -->
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@6.1.1/umd/react-router.development.js" crossorigin></script>
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.1.1/umd/react-router-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
> ```

```
const BrowserRouter = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
const Routes = ReactRouterDOM.Routes;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
          
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: How do you know react-router-dom is exported as ReactRouterDOM? Is there any documentation for those things?

Comment: Now the error becomes "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Routes')" Is there anything wrong with other parts of the code?